# WooCommerce display single error message in checkout for one error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On my checkout in WooCommerce I've check if there are a least 2 checkboxes set. If both of them are not checked, I'm getting two error messages but within one message container:

```
<ul class="woocommerce-error" role="alert">
    <li>Error one</li>
    <li>Error two</li>
</ul>
```

What I want ix this here:

```
<ul class="woocommerce-error" role="alert">
    <li>Error one</li>
</ul>

<ul class="woocommerce-error" role="alert">
    <li>Error two</li>
</ul>
```

I'm adding my error messages this way:

```
/**
 * Validate the revocation checkout policy checkbox
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'validate_revocation_policy' );
function validate_revocation_policy() {
    if ( ! (int)isset( $_POST['revocation_policy_one'] ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( get_option( 'work_revocation_checkout_policy_checkbox_error_text_one' ) ), 'error' );
    }

    if ( ! (int)isset( $_POST['revocation_policy_two'] ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( get_option( 'work_revocation_checkout_policy_checkbox_error_text_two' ) ), 'error' );
    }

}
```

Comment: Found the part where I can change it very easily :D.!

Comment: If it's so easy then answer your own question as it will be helpful for the community…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I'm currently on a business travel. I'll do this when I'm home. Please understand this :) Thanks!